# Отцы и дети)))

Tags: этимология, словообразование, недопустимая-метка

Почему название детенышей животных не всегда является производным от названия родителя? Например, "кошка - котенок", "тигр - тигренок", но при этом "собака - щенок", "лошадь - жеребенок", "курица - цыпленок". Да что там говорить, даже "человек - ребенок"!

Answer (score 1):

В общем-то ответ DocentI правильный. С одним уточнением. Дело не просто в том, что домашние животные близки к человеку, а в том, что самец, самка и детеныши  выполняют принципиально разную роль.
Кошка и собака - животные не совсем домашние, так сказать - дворовые,  в смысле хозяйственной деятельности занимают промежуточное положение между домашними и дикими.   Поэтому к ним и отношение особое - общее правило на них как бы не распространяется. Собаки получили разные названия видимо в силу того, что культура их разведения очень древняя, кошки же до недавнего времени плодились и размножались достаточно стихийно, различать пол и возораст животного большой практической нужды не было.
Нечто подобное, видимо, произошло и с козами.

Answer (score 0):

Заметьте, что наибольшие различия возникают там, где животное близко к человеку, используется в его (хозяйственной) деятельности. Видимо, "кошка" в этом ряду, как всегда, гуляет сама по себе!

Интересно было бы провести сравнение с другими языками.

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, поначалу людьми для разных существ/предметов придумывались отдельные, уникальные слова (овца - баран - ягненок, корова - бык - теленок и пр.). Поэтому те животные, которые были одомашнены первыми, имеют несколько слов для их наименования. Позже названия стали "унифицироваться", отсюда "котята", "козлята" и пр.